# How to enable/disable windows defender on schedule

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-defender

I want to enable/disable `Windows Defender` via `Task Scheduler`. The reason I want this is because I'm running an automatic backup via `Backup and Restore (Windows 7)` option and it keeps failing because of a false positive that I've excluded in Windows Defender! I've tried manually disabling `Real-time protection` and the backup succeeds. I know how to set up `Task Scheduler` to run `.cmd` etc. script files. So here is the question:

How can I disable Windows Defender right before the backup runs daily, and how can I enable it afterwards?

I've tried these commands but they don't seem to work:

```
sc stop/start WinDefend (does not stop Defender, gives access denied even with admin right)
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true/$false (does not seem to do anything)
```

Comment: The Set-MpPreference command can only be set to $true or $false. It won't work if you put $true/$false. Also, this edits the local group policy on the machine, so the change won't kick in until your next reboot. Test it works manually by right clicking powershell and opening it as admin.

Comment: Also worth double checking if you're able to turn off windows defender using the group policy app yourself manually. Just to make sure it works: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender

Comment: @Mastaxx I'm not putting "$true/$false", I wrote it that way to not write the same thing twice. Thank your clarifying why it did not seem to work, because it needed a reboot! Coming to your second comment, if I'm going to manually disable it, I can do it through the GUI, but the whole idea is automating it so my daily backup can run without me interfering. I don't want to disable the thing every night and re-enabling it the following morning :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and I found a way to disable it with Task Scheduler. For your use case, you'll just have to change triggers to your liking. Here is what I did with a friend: https://github.com/duttyend/Microsoft-Defender-RTP-stop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).